# Powershell script strange behaviour when invoked from CMD/CLI

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, user-interface, ui-automation

This scripts works fine when executed from Powershell console...
but does not work when executed with Powershell.exe from CMD.exe...
(`powershell.exe -file script.ps1`, using Powershell 5.1.17763.771)

```
# display Windows Shell Folder propertes
$App  = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;
$AppNS = $App.NameSpace( "c:\windows" );
$AppNS.Self.InvokeVerb( "Properties" );
```

I tested other GUI objects (Winforms & WPF)
and they work fine...

?any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **the in-process COM object you're creating goes out of scope when the calling process exits**, which in your case, when called from `cmd.exe` via PowerShell's CLI, means that the window typically never even gets a chance to display or is automatically closed after a very brief appearance.

- **In an *interactive* PowerShell session**, the process lives on after exiting the script - that's why your code works there.
- **When you invoke a script via via *PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)*** (`powershell.exe` for *Windows PowerShell*, `pwsh` for PowerShell *Core*, without the `-NoExit` switch to keep the process alive indefinitely), the PowerShell process *exits* when the script terminates.

---

Use of `-NoExit` would be a stopgap at best, because it would keep the PowerShell process around *indefinitely*, even though you presumably want it to live only for as long as the Properties dialog window is open - whenever the user chooses to close it.

Therefore, **you need to *synchronously* wait for (a) the Properties dialog window to open and then (b) wait for it close before exiting the script.**

You can do this with the help of the .NET [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) library as follows; note that the code uses PowerShell v5+ syntax:

```bsh
using namespace System.Windows.Automation

# Load the UI Automation client assemblies.
# Requires Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core v7+ (on Windows only).
Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationClient; Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationTypes

# Initiate display of the Windows folder's Properties dialog.
$App = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$AppNS = $App.NameSpace('c:\windows')
$AppNS.Self.InvokeVerb('Properties')

# Comment out this line to suppress the verbose messages.
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Write-Verbose 'Wating for the window''s creation...'
do {
  # Search among the current process' top-level windows for a winow
  # with class name '#32770', which is what the Properties dialog windows
  # use (don't know why, but it has been stable over time).
  $w = [AutomationElement]::RootElement.FindFirst([TreeScope]::Children, 
    [AndCondition]::new(
      [PropertyCondition]::new([AutomationElement]::ClassNameProperty, '#32770'),
      [PropertyCondition]::new([AutomationElement]::ProcessIdProperty, $PID)
    )
  )
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
} while (-not $w)

Write-Verbose 'Window has appeared, waiting for it to close...'

while ($w.Current.ProcessId) {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

Write-Verbose 'Window is now closed, moving on.'

# At this point, if the script was invoked via PowerShell's CLI (powershell.exe -file ...)
# the PowerShell process terminates.
```

Now, invoking your PowerShell script as follows from your batch file will pop up the Properties dialog *and wait for it to close* before continuing:

```
@echo off

::  # ... your batch file

::  # Pop up the Properties dialog and *wait for it to close*.
powershell.exe -file script.ps1

::  # ...
```

If, by contrast, you simply want to *launch* the Properties dialog while continuing to run your batch file (be sure to disable the verbose messages first):

```
:: # Only *initiate* display of the Properties dialog and *continue execution*.
start /B powershell.exe -file script.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it has to wait for the graphics to finish.  "get-childitem | out-gridview" does a similar thing.  Or add "sleep 120" to the end of the script, or find some other way to wait.  Killing the script kills the window.

```
powershell -noexit .\explorer.ps1
```

Comment: Indeed with no exit results (leaving the Powershell console open, what is not desirable)... Nevertheless I already try pausing the program with "Read-host" at the end of the script and the result is the same... ???!!!

Comment: Strangely... using start-sleep <n-seconds> works... but pausing with Read-Host does not work...

Comment: @Zee: `Read-Host` blocks the UI thread, so the window doesn't get a chance to display; if you precede it with something like `Start-Sleep 5`, you'll see that it comes up.