# Using script such as Powershell to do batch data entry

Tags: powershell

I have a **Windows 10** data entry application that has no API to directly interface with it. I want to write a script that will populate the appropriate fields with data provided from a .CSV file or clipboard or somesuch buffer.

My research points toward Powershell, but I'm not married to it. I can certainly open a .CSV and have it spew one record at a time to the console.

Can I get it to target my application? i.e. If the data entry application is open to a 'New Record' form, I'd like the script to populate the fields with the data from the .CSV file one at a time.

I know there will be a fair amount of complexity as to how to target the right fields and such - ideally I can tell the script to send TAB characters to move between fields, and to send a Ctrl-F character to trigger the 'Find Record' feature.

Baby steps. Step #1 is **getting the script to send its output to the data entry application**. What needs to happen to facilitate that?

Comment: Powershell needs an API to trigger and you don't have one. The only API you have is actual on screen windows. AutoIt is pretty good at automating that. I suggest you investigate AutoIt

Comment: There's also [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation).

Comment: @mklement0 Since UI automation is part of the .NET framework, it can be used within Powershell?

Comment: @arealhobo, yes; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307981/45375) for an example.