# How to create a macro (not excel) in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, macros

I need to macro some certain keystrokes and mouseclicks and Powershell would be a preferable language.

The code below is copied from Stackoverflow, it enables me to use the mouse and the keyboard.

```
$cSource = @'
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class Clicker
{
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct INPUT
{ 
    public int        type; // 0 = INPUT_MOUSE,
                            // 1 = INPUT_KEYBOARD
                            // 2 = INPUT_HARDWARE
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
}

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int    dx ;
    public int    dy ;
    public int    mouseData ;
    public int    dwFlags;
    public int    time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

//This covers most use cases although complex mice may have additional buttons
//There are additional constants you can use for those cases, see the msdn page
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVED      = 0x0001 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN   = 0x0002 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP     = 0x0004 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN  = 0x0008 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP    = 0x0010 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP   = 0x0040 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL      = 0x0080 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN      = 0x0100 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_XUP        = 0x0200 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE   = 0x8000 ;

const int screen_length = 0x10000 ;

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);

public static void LeftClickAtPoint(int x, int y)
{
    //Move the mouse
    INPUT[] input = new INPUT[3];
    input[0].mi.dx = x*(65535/System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
    input[0].mi.dy = y*(65535/System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVED | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    //Left mouse button down
    input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    //Left mouse button up
    input[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(3, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input[0]));
}
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSource -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
```

With the given code, I can use these commands:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')
[Clicker]::LeftClickAtPoint(600,600)
$wshell.SendKeys('f')
```

Ideally this would ALT+TAB to my previous window, clicks at position 600,600 and then presses key F
However it doesn't work, since after switching windows, powershell goes back to the code and presses in the ISE with the cursor.

I need advices or some code snippets about how to automate mouse clicks, movements and keyboard clicks in an other window.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest looking into the .NET [UI Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview); a simple example of its use is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307981/45375).

Comment: can you use a 3rd party util? the `AutoIT` user interface automation stuff has a PoSh module that can do quite a lot with standard apps ... [*grin*]